# How do you get the hoodie for Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've seen footage of Shepard with a hoodie in ME3.

Is this an accomplishment or something? Or is it a mod and not actually available in the game?

Answer (score 7):

The hoodie is part of the N7 Collector's and N7 Digital Deluxe Editions.  As far as I know, there currently is no other way of getting it.

Answer (score 3):

The N7 Hoodie is one of the items that comes with the collectors, or Digital Deluxe edition of Mass Effect 3. This is the only way of aquiring it.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are partly correct, however an additional way is available although out of the picture at this stage, that option was to **preorder on origin**.

However since the game is out that is impossible, the only way now is to buy the **collecters edition**, but i think that is sold out everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to own the collectors edition, but if you want it buying it new is the only way as the code will have been used otherwise. I have the hoodie IRL but when I buy the collectors edition for collectors purpose as I have the other two. I may buy it new for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to own the Mass Effect 3 Deluxe Edition. It can be purchased [here](https://www.origin.com/en-gb/store/buy/mass-effect-3/pc-download/base-game/digital-deluxe-edition) or, if you already own the base game, you can upgrade to the duluxe edition [here](https://www.origin.com/en-gb/store/buy/mass-effect-3/pc-download/addon/mass-effect-3-digital-deluxe-edition-upgrade).